# AttributeError: module 'app.parse' has no attribute 'sheet'

Tags: python, django

I got an error: `AttributeError: module 'app.parse' has no attribute 'sheet4'` .
In **parse.py** I wrote

```
class DataRate():
    data_rate ={}
    data_rate =defaultdict(dict)
    def try_to_int(arg):
        try:
            return int(arg)
        except:
            return arg

    book4 = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
    sheet4 = book4.sheet_by_index(0)
```

in **data_rate_savedata.py**

```
from . import parse
def data_rate_save():
   for row_index in range(0, sheet4.nrows):
        row = sheet4.row_values(row_index)
        row = list(map(try_to_int, row))
        value = dict(zip(tag_list, row))

        closing_rate_dict[value['ID']].update(value)
        user = User.objects.filter(corporation_id=closing_rate_dict[value['ID']]['NAME'])
```

in **main_save.py**

```
from app.parse import DataRate

#parse
DataRate()
#save
data_rate_save()
```

When I run main_save.py, the error occurrs. I really cannot understand why this error happens because I import parse.py in data_rate_savedata.py, so I can access  parse.py of 'sheet4' in data_rate_savedata.py. Should I write something in main_save.py? How can I fix this error?
in **models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    trunsaction_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
```

Full traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/app/data_rate_savedata.py", line 11, in <module>
    data_rate_save()
  File "/Users/app/data_rate_savedata.py", line 19, in data_rate_save
    for row_index in range(0, sheet4.nrows):
AttributeError: module 'app.parse' has no attribute 'sheet4'
```

Comment: show your models.py

Comment: why you use `from . import parse` and not just `import parse` ?

Comment: @amrit I updated my question.If u know something please help me.

Comment: @Vinny Because if I use import parse, terminal told parse cannot be find.When I use from . import pars, the error is ok

Comment: Can you add full error text?

Comment: Try to add before your import statements `import sys; sys.path.append('.')` to solve your `from . import ..` thing.

Comment: @Vinny I added import sys; ~~ but same error happens.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I added full traceback

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @amrit I wanna parse excel& put the data to User model when I run command from app import main_save

Comment: You are reading the excel file in the wrong way...try this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python  @user8563636

Comment: @amrit Oh really? I read ur link page, but I cannot understand what is wrong.What should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `data_rate_savedata.py`, try:

```
from .parse import DataRate

# and use
# DataRate.sheet4
```

I guess `sheet4` is a  attribute of DataRate, not parse.