# switching a specific part of URL and save the result to CSV

Tags: python, api, web-crawler

I have an excel that has 'ID' key and API call URL

**the Excel looks like this:**

[image]

**And the URL is this:**

> http://api.*******.com/2.0/location/{property_id}?key=123456ASDFG

The result of the API call is in JSON format

I would like to iterate the excel's property_id in the URL and save the result to csv in each row.

what I did so far is

> import requests
>
> import json
>
> url = "http://api.*******.com/2.0/location/{property_id}?key=123456ASDFG"
>
> response = requests.get(url)
>
> data = response.test
>
> print data

the result is basically same as what I just put the url in Chrome browser

I somehow have to read each row in the excel column A and switch the value and insert into {property_id} in the url
then, append the result to csv as row number increases..

I'm very new to API and I have no idea where to start.
I was trying to find similar questions on Stack-overflow and could not find any. (maybe wrong keywords?)

Any help is very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: https://python.gotrained.com/python-json-api-tutorial/ .. I think I can start from here. the thing is i do not know how to iterate the url in the excel's property_id column.

Comment: I search for `python read excel` and found some questions that are useful to start working with Excel file, like [Read Excel File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python) or [Reading/parsing Excel xls files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python). Hope it can help.