# Creating folder structure from .xlsx

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I’ve got an .xlsx file with a certain structure (check the image please) and I would like it to process the containing information to a certain folder structure via `mkdir`, the only thing I have is an .xlsx and the name of the folder is a String from the first 3 contens of the .xlsx (maybe I must work with VBA?):

At the end of the process, there should be 3 new folders with a picture and .txt file inside

Here it is what it sould look like in the end --> [workflow and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixlc8.png)

The URL of an .png should be dropped into that created folder, as well as one single .txt file containing the two ProdDec (Production Description) and Collection content.

I have python 3.6.x installed and PowerShell is also on my win7 64x machine.

Many thanks

Rainer Zufall

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python) and [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and then give an example of some code you would write so we can help you better

Comment: Thank you for the links, I muts say, I have been there before, but it really does not help, its not generating any new folders (mkdir). Well actually I have built an .xlsx File and I would like to generate via mkdir folders. The name of the new generated folders should be the first 3 lines on the excel (as you can see on the picture), also I would like to save the .png directly in this folder, not an url. Also the .txt should be deployed into the new folder. Right now i am trying to get a code together, but I really don't understand what i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in your Excel file using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io), gather the appropriate information, and then create a directory for each product. The images can be downloaded using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library. Below is a tested solution to your problem:

```
import os

import openpyxl
import requests

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('A1.xlsx')

sheet = wb.active

rows = [tuple(cell.value for cell in row if cell.value is not None) for row in sheet] # convert the cells to text

dirnames = list()
images = list()
text = list()

for row in rows[1:]: # [1:], ignore column headers for better looping
    if row[0] is not None:
        dirnames.append('_'.join(row[:3])) # joins the Brand, Family, and Ref columns
        images.append(row[3:-2]) # stores the uris in a tuple
        text.append('\r\n'.join(row[-2:])) # joins the last two columns

for i in range(len(dirnames)):
    if not(os.path.exists(dirnames[i])):
        os.mkdir(dirnames[i]) # create the dir
    os.chdir(dirnames[i]) # enter the dir
    print('creating', dirnames[i])
    for j, image in enumerate(images[i]): # for all of the images
        imagereq = requests.get(image)
        imagename = 'Img{}.png'.format(j + 1)
        if imagereq.status_code == 200: # prevents filewriting errors for bad requests
            with open(imagename, 'wb') as fp:
                fp.write(imagereq.content)
            print(' ' * 4 + 'image write successful for', imagename)
        else:
            print(' ' * 4 + 'could not download image {}, error'.format(imagename), imagereq.status_code, imagereq.reason)
    with open('ProdDesc_and_Collection.txt', 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(text[i].encode('utf8'))

    os.chdir('..') # back out of the dir
```

**UPDATE**: Code now works for multiple images per product and ignores empty cells

Comment: Hi Clay, wow, thank you, I could never have thought of that! I have two more feedbacks: 1) Line 17 (dirnames.append) gives me an Error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found. 2) What if I have 2 or more images to store? do I just cope the section of "if imagereq" to "print('could not download image, error'..."

Comment: 1) Which one of your cells blank? 2) Do you have additional columns or do the links have a delimiter within the cell?

Comment: I just uploaded the .xlsx on http://www.dongiatti.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/For_Clay.xlsx actually no no cell is blank, or am I missing something? No delimiter

Comment: Thank you so much for your work! Let me know If I can do you a favor in any kind ,except coding :)

Comment: Hi Clay, sorry to reach out for you again, my final file does not go through:

text.append('\n'.join(row[-2:])) # joins the last two columns
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

I tried several things, recreat a new file, searching vo delimiters etc.
http://www.dongiatti.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/A1.xlsx

Comment: @RainerZufall Done

Comment: Hi Clay, sorry for the interruption, to hope this is the last time. I am trying to loop the image names and text names, as “Brand_Family_Ref_1” i.e. “Cartier_Baignoire_WB520003_1.png”. If there are multiple pictures it goes_2, _3 etc. This also for the .txt: “Brand_Family_Ref_info_en”  i.e. “Cartier_Baignoire_WB520003_info_en.txt”. I am really sorry to bother you again…I tried imagename = dirnames{}.png.format(j + 1) and I tried many more, but I am just messing up the code.

Comment: Try `dirname` as the first formatting argument or just concatenate. Ex. `'{}_{}.png'.format(dirname, j + 1)` or `dirname + '_{}.png'.format(j + 1)`

Comment: Thank you Clay! imagename = dirnames[i] + '_{}.png'.format(j + 1) did the trick...also i tried the sam ething for the text:     for texts in enumerate(text): # for all of the images
        textname = dirnames[i] + '_info_en.txt'
        with open(textname, 'wb') as fp:
             fp.write(text[i].encode('utf8'))
I really learned the trick! Thank you Clay, if you wish a shipment from www.dongiatti.com, please give me a pm! Thank you!

Comment: I feel like a complete fool. If I delete the .xlsx and and have all the folder and files in there, how do I get the .xlsx back in the same structure? Maybe it’s an overkill….I tried something with “import xlsxwriter” and “workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Cartier_reverse.xlsx')

Comment: Did you delete the file on accident? It should be in your recycle bin

Comment: I wish :) no I have the file from Cartier still. The problem is, for 98% I get the .xlsx out and now a friend provied me direct the folder structure...and I need always both types (.xlsx & Folder) and now i am working on an reverse engineering to get the .xlsx out. from the folder structure -.-

Comment: Yeah, that's the right approach. List the folders and create the list of tuples I created in the forward version. The write the contents after the headers. Are the number of images the same for each of the products?

Comment: ok I will try, yes all the files are the same, same structure. I will try it with the Cartier, so i don't mess up the code with new information

Comment: May I show you the current code somewhere? If its too much work to correct it, i might just go to freelance.com oder upwork, or also send you the funds