# Trouble reading excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file which has numerical data of a matrix of dimension `30 x 30`. I am trying to read it and access individual element as normally done. But I am getting a list instead of a single element.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xl  = pd.ExcelFile('sample.xlsx')
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')

data = np.matrix(df1)
print(data.shape)

print(data[0])
print(data[0][0])
```

**Output**

```
(30, 30)
[[ 0  0  7  0  4  0  3  0  0  7  4  0  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0
   0  0  4  0 10  3]]
[[ 0  0  7  0  4  0  3  0  0  7  4  0  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0
   0  0  4  0 10  3]]
```

Any thoughts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python ... please go through the link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
import pandas as pd 
import xlrd as xl 
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile 

df=pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Apart from above, there are a bunch of answers for this question. Please go through them:-

[Read Excel File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python)

Comment: all I have to do is use `data[0, 0]` instead of `data[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can read excel using xlrd module.Below code you can try to read the first column of the Excel.

```
import xlrd

loc = ("Excel_path")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
row_count = sheet.nrows
while (n<row_count):
    data=sheet.cell_value(n, 0)#to read data from first column of excel
```

In `data=sheet.cell_value(n, 0)`  you can replace 0 with 1 to read next column and so on.