# How to read from excel and write in json file using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, xlsx

I am trying to create a json file which reads data from test.xlsx. My sample code is below.

Instead of "WO-12345" and other values, I want that to be read from the excel sheet, like I want it to be read from a particular cell in excel.

```
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import simplejson as json
import json

jsonfile = open('data1.json', 'w')
data_list = []
data = OrderedDict()

data['workOrder'] = "WO-12345"
data['alternateStart'] = "2018-01-13T10:00:00Z"
data['mobileNumber'] = "(555) 555-5555"
data['officeNumber'] = "(555) 555-5554"
data['description'] = "Testing"
data['equipment'] = "Testing"

data_list.append(data)

j = json.dumps(data_list)


json.dump(data, jsonfile, indent=3, sort_keys=False)
jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Excel File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read an Excel there's pandas `pandas.read_excel`, it returns a `pandas.DataFrame` that has the `to_json` method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html