# Reading Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a function that needs two arguments: user and password, both of them are strings. My problem is that I want to get the arguments from an Excel file (user and password) How can I do it? :(

[image]

The function looks like this (I'm using Selenium with Chrome):

```py
def login(user,passwd):
    createDir()
    driver.get('https://www.fasab2b.com/FasaCL/BBRe-commerce/access/login.do')
    driver.maximize_window()
    txtId = driver.find_element_by_id("logid")
    passw = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    txtId.send_keys(user)
    passw.send_keys(passwd)
    passw.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I want to execute the function with something like this:

```py
for user,password in excelFile:
    login(user,password)
    print("login made with: " + user + password)
```

Thankful for any help

Comment: Have you looked into libraries for Python & Excel? http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Use Pandas .. you'll enjoy it.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Excel File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

This is how to access a worksheet from an existing Excel file.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data/test.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

So it is very easy to create, for example, a function returning a list of tuples from all the rows (from the second, skipping the header, to the last one) and from specific columns (3 and 4, again in your example) of a given Excel file

```
def excelLogins(path):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ret = []
    for i in range(2,ws.max_row + 1):
        ret.append((ws.cell(i,3).value,str(ws.cell(i,4).value)))
    return ret
```

Since your passwords would be interpreted as numbers from Excel, you might also want to convert them to strings, as already done above.
Eventually, you can print the results as you prefer

```
for user,password in excelLogins('data/test.xlsx'):
    print("login made with: " + user + ':' + password)
```