# Import named range from Excel into Python script

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet with a named range.
I am trying to extract each column of the named range as a list.

I have written a script so that Python can identify the cell range ( in this case, F4:H10), as shown.

I now want to assign a list for each column, i.e.
Height = [100, 200, 400, 200, 300].

I tried following the method attached: [Read Excel File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python)

However, I need to use defined ranges, as I move the spreadsheet around often, and can't afford to go through the python script each time I rearrange the excel sheet, and pandas wanted me to identify the column as the letter of the column the table is in.

```
file = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only = True)

address = list(wb.defined_names['mytest'].destinations)

for sheetname, cellAddress in address:
    cellAddress = cellAddress.replace('$', '')
    print(cellAddress)
```

[image: This is the spreadsheet named range]

Comment: What's the actual question? Looks like you've found the defined names.

Comment: I want to create a Python list of the columns of my defined range, so that I can have Height = [ 100, 200, 400, 200, 300]

Comment: So you want the values from the cells in the range?